# Scraping from Facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, web-scraping, request

I have a challenge I'm running into and cannot seem to find an answer for it anywhere on the web. I'm working on a personal project; it's a Node.js application that uses the request and cheerio packages to hit an end-point and scrape some data... However, the endpoint is a Facebook page... and the display of its content is dependent upon whether the user is logged in or not.

In short, the app seeks to scrape the user's saved links, you know, all that stuff you add to your "save for later" but never actually go back to (at least in my case). The end-point, then, is [htpps://www.facebook.com/saved](http://www.facebook.com/saved). If, in your browser, you are logged into Facebook, clicking that link will take you where the application needs to go. However, since the application isn't technically going through the browser that has your credentials and your session saved, I'm running into a bit of an issue...

Yes, using the request module I'm able to successfully reach "a" part of Facebook, but not the one I need... My question really is: how should I begin to handle this challenge?

This is all the code I have for the app so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', (req, res) => {
  // Workspace
  var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/saved';
  request(url, (err, response, html) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(html));
  })

})

app.listen('8081', () => {
  console.log('App listening on port 8081');
})
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated... Currently, I'm on hold...! **How could I possibly hit this end-point with credentials (safely) provided by the user so that the application could get legitimately get past authentication and reach the desired end-point?**

Comment: I looked into their API but it doesn't allow for what I'm trying to accomplish... it seems like that feature was available at some point in the not so distant past, but it's gone now :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish that using request-cheerio module since you need to make a post request with your login information.

A headless browser is more appropriate for this kind of project if you want it to be a scraper. Try using [casperJs](http://casperjs.org/) or [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). It will give you more flexibility but it's not a node.js module so you need to make a step further if you want to incorporate it with express.

One nodeJs module I know that can let you post is [Osmosis](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis/wiki#login). If you can make .login(user, pw) to work then that'll be great but I don't think it can successfully login to facebook though.

API if possible would be a much nicer solution but I'm assuming you already looked it up and find nothing in there for what you are looking for.

My personal choice would be to use an RobotProcessAutomation. [WinAutomation](http://www.winautomation.com/), for example, is a great tool for manipulating web and scraping. It's a whole new different approach but it can do the job well and can be implemented faster compared to programmatically coding it.